# WPF Converter written in F# is not recognized

Tags: wpf, f#, ivalueconverter

I wrote the following converter in F#

```
namespace My.FSharpLibrary

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Linq
open System.Text
open System.Threading.Tasks
open System.Globalization
open System.Windows.Data

type ValueCompareConverter() =
    member val ReferenceValue = Unchecked.defaultof<float> with get,set
    interface IValueConverter with
        member this.Convert(value,targetType,parameter,culture) =
            let f = float (value.ToString())

            match parameter.ToString() with
                | "LessThan" -> f < this.ReferenceValue :> obj
                | "GreaterThan" -> f > this.ReferenceValue :> obj
                | _ -> failwith "Invalid Converter parameter"; false :> obj

        member this.ConvertBack(value,targetType,parameter,culture) =
            failwith "Not implemented"
```

I can see this converter in `Object Browser` but when I add reference to my library in my C# WPF project and add the following xaml code

```
... xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:My.FSharpLibrary" ...

...

 <helpers:ValueCompareConverter ReferenceValue="0.0" x:Key="compareToZeroConverter"  />
```

I get the following error

> Error 140 The name "ValueCompareConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:My.FSharpLibrary".

Any clue ?

Answer (score 3):

duh!

I had to add `assembly=My.FSharpLibrary` to the namespace definition

```
 <Window xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:My.FSharpLibrary;assembly=My.FSharpLibrary"  />
```